# Social Media Button Positioning

Tags: html, css

I want to place social media side menu on the side of an iframe

I've tried place the social media side menu within an  tag that was placed in the same  as the iframe.

```
<div>
    <p align="center"><iframe src="https://rucode.tumblr.com" width="1200" height="1400" align="middle" class="embeded-website"></iframe></p>
    <aside class="side-social-media">
        <nav>
            <ul class="vertical-menu">
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011425754260" target="_blank" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/Mike_doug11" target="_blank"class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/michael-douglas11" target="_blank" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCihoOa4CmCOFH_TE1-Utp-A?view_as=subscriber" target="_blank"class="fa fa-youtube"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/mike_doug11/" target="_blank"class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.snapchat.com/add/mike_douglas" target="_blank" class="fa fa-snapchat-ghost"></a></li>
             </ul>
         </nav>
    </aside>

<div>
```

When I do this the social media side menu is off to the side but its below the iframe.

Comment: can you please add your css? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS bottom or top property like below

```
<style>    
    .vertical-menu{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0; /* or bottom: 0;*/
    }
<style>
<div>
    <p align="center"><iframe src="https://rucode.tumblr.com" width="1200" height="1400" align="middle" class="embeded-website"></iframe></p>
    <aside class="side-social-media">
        <nav>
            <ul class="vertical-menu">
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011425754260" target="_blank" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/Mike_doug11" target="_blank"class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/michael-douglas11" target="_blank" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCihoOa4CmCOFH_TE1-Utp-A?view_as=subscriber" target="_blank"class="fa fa-youtube"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/mike_doug11/" target="_blank"class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.snapchat.com/add/mike_douglas" target="_blank" class="fa fa-snapchat-ghost"></a></li>
             </ul>
         </nav>
    </aside>

<div>
```